# How do i sort an array of structs alphabetically while contents stay associated

Tags: c++, struct

```
struct Album {
  string title;
  string year;
  string track;
  vector<string> tracks;
}MyAlbums[5];


int j;
Album temp;
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
  j = i - 1;
  while( j >= 0 && strcmp( MyAlbums[j+1].title[0], MyAlbums[j].title[0]) < 0 ){
    temp =  MyAlbums[j + 1];
    MyAlbums[j+1] = MyAlbums[j];
    MyAlbums[j] = temp;
    j--;
  }
}
```

gives me this: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Use `std::sort()` and define `operator<()` for `Album`.

Comment: structs arent handled as pointers by default (unlike arrays), so temp should be `Album *temp;`

Comment: @x4rf41: What are you talking about?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you could define an efficient swap function for `Album`. `void swap(Album &lhs, Album &rhs) { using std::swap; swap(lhs.title, rhs.title); swap(lhs.year, rhs.year); swap(lhs.track, rhs.track); swap(lhs.tracks, rhs.tracks); }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++

```
struct Album {
  string title;
  string year;
  string track;
  vector<string> tracks;

  bool operator<(const Album &a) const
  {
      return title.compare(a.title) > 0;
  }
} MyAlbums[5];

std::sort(std::begin(MyAlbums), std::end(MyAlbums));
```

C++11

```
std::sort(std::begin(MyAlbums), std::end(MyAlbums), [](const Album &a1, const Album &a2 ){
    return a1.title.compare(a2.title) > 0;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is appearing, because, you are comparing `MyAlbums[j+1].title[0]`; the first element of `std::string`, which is a `char` (or a `const char`) but not a `const char*`!

Probably you want:

```
strcmp(MyAlbums[j+1].title.c_str(), MyAlbums[j].title.c_str())) < 0
```

Which is syntax wise correct, but not sure about the logic.

Since you are using C++, you can think about using [`std::sort(..)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

The other alternative is to change your design and use [`std::map(..)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/). Here all your data will be in *order*, which can be iterated using iterators (forward or backward). On the other hand, you will have an easy access using map keys.

Answer (score 1):

You are using STL classes so why you want to use `strcmp` when you have `title.compare(title2)`?

You are also using it in a not proper way since you are trying to compare two `char` (`title[0]`) instead that `char*`.

You could use a custom comparator like

```
struct cmp_str {
  bool operator()(const Album &a, const Album &b) {
    return a.title.compare(b.title) < 0;
  }
};
```

and sort the collection accordingly with `std:sort(..)`

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` takes a `const char*`.

`MyAlbums[j+1].title[0]` returns a `char`.

Your best bet is use `std::sort` and define `operator<()` for `Album`. You can also use `.c_str()` on `title`.

More info on [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` has a compare method you can use.

```
while( j >= 0 && MyAlbums[j+1].title.compare(MyAlumbus[j].title) < 0)
{ ... }
```

Also,

`MyAlumbus[j].title[0]` calls an overloaded `operator[]` on a `std::string` which pulls out the first character.

`strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 )` is the signature for `strcmp`. It expects a `char *`, while you're just providing a `char`.